# 2 Java updates needed?

Tags: windows-7, java

The picture below is a cropped snapshot of the programs and features section of my control panel on windows 7.
[image: A cropped view of windows7's programs and features section]
Notice I have 2 Java things (Update 22 and Update 24). Is this needed, or can I uninstall update 22?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless they represent separate 32-bit and 64-bit versions, you can safely uninstall the Update 22 version.  If they are separate 32-bit and 64-bit versions, don't uninstall either version, as they are separate products; if so, they also need to be updated independently.  Should this break the Java system, you can try uninstalling all versions and installing the latest version from http://www.java.com.

This problem may be caused by bugs in the Java Updater, since it had notified me several times about updates even though the latest update is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

Java is quite horrid about leaving behind old versions - so much at one point i had nearly a dozen different java updates installed, and its safe to remove them - i just tend to run [JavaRa](http://raproducts.org/wordpress/software) periodically (its a software that removes old versions of java) since its a pain to keep uninstalling old versions manually.

Comment: Java hasn't done this by default for a while now.  Since 6u10, IIRC.